# Get Access Token from Facebook with out redirect log-in page

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

```
 private void CheckAuthorization()
{
    string app_id = "*************";
    string app_secret = "*************";
    string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

    if (Request["code"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(string.Format(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
            app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
    }
    else
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
            app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
            {
                tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                    token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
            }
        }

        string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

        var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "Test Posts";
        parameters.link = "http://blog.mysite.com";
        parameters.picture = "http://blog.mysite.com/images/logo.png";
        parameters.description = "Test Post";
        parameters.name = "Test Post";
        parameters.caption = "Welcome to test post";
        client.Post("/me/feed", parameters);
    }
}
```

Hi, 
 The Above method is get Access token from Facebook and post on my Facebook wall. But if request[code] is null it is redirecting to Facebook log in page and asking user name and password. My requirement is is there any way  to get access token from Facebook with out log in? or way to log in with out redirect to Facebook log in page like silent or background log in and get access token by request[code]?

Thank you for supporting....

Comment: How can i enter your home without maindoor keys.

Comment: of-course its need. but is there any way to log-in without showing lo-gin page...